# cakephp email object notify on failure

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I have this code in my cakephp 2 installation to send out emails

```
if($Email->template('invitation', 'default')
                        ->emailFormat('html')
                        ->from(array('no-reply@domain.com' => 'MyHospitals'))
                        ->to($email)
                        ->subject($subject)
                        ->send()){
```

This works fine as long as smtp settings and everything is fine. However if someone changes the password, this fails miserably ....is there a check I can add that will tell me that $Email object was formatted correctly so that if it was not, I can kill it gracefully instead of having errors showing up on the page

thanks

Comment: have you tried `try - catch` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    if ($Email->template('invitation', 'default')
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->from(array('no-reply@domain.com' => 'MyHospitals'))
        ->to($email)
        ->subject($subject)
        ->send()) {
        // Do success stuff
    } else {
        // Handle failure (no exception thrown)
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle exceptions
}
```

Comment: `CakeEmail::send()` always returns an array with `headers` and `message` keys, so the `if`/`else` won't do anything, all failures are to be handled in the `catch` block.